# Printf doesn't append to file but echo does?

Tags: shell, tcsh

I have inherited some code and the following line is apparently used to write a string to a file; but the file remains empty.

```
printf $msg > $file
```

This code works fine, so I'm happy both variables are defined and populated.

```
echo $msg > $file
```

However if I run the first example in my shell it also works fine (albeit with strings instead of variables). Any ideas what could be going on behind the scenes here, or what the fundamental difference is between the two? I have Google'd and tried various iterations of the first code, such as the following, but the problem seems to be how printf works.

```
printf "%s" $msg > $file
```

Comment: Try `echo "$msg" > $file` and `printf "%s\n" "$msg" > $file`

Comment: It depends on the content of `$msg`.